# How to keep my navigation stick to the top?

Tags: html, css, navigation, sticky

I've been trying some diffrent tutorials on how to get my navbar stick to the top while scrolling but can't get it to work :/

This is the page i'm having troubles with:
http://www.vernietig.be/vcs/index.html

Thanks in advance for helping me out on this one!

Comment: A tip: Make a special rule using [media queries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6370690/453331) for smaller viewports (e.g. mobile devices), so the menu isn't sticky there. It's a huge annoyance trying to read something on a small phone screen where half of the website is the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will stick your navigation on top :

```
 #yourTopNav{
    top : 0;
    position : fixed;
    }
```

Comment: tried to add those 2 rules but when added to: 
.nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

OR

.nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
Nav dissapears... When I try to add it to a new .nav-collapse {}
nothing changes....

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
body { margin-top: 55px; }
nav { position: fixed; clip: auto; }
```

I don't know why you have that `clip: rect(0,0,0,0)` but that hides the whole menu, you may even have to inline that directive, or remove the `.nav-collapse` class that causes it (but I don't really know how is your menu supposed to work :P).

Comment: added those 2 rules in the head to be sure it gets loaded last but doesn't work...

Comment: Oh that's because of rule specificity, for example, if you assign an `id` to your `nav`, and change the second line to `#nav_id { position: fixed; clip: auto; }` it'll be the last rule applied.